# Prism: New Project vs. New Module and Communication Between Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am working on a Prism/WPF Project and I already have a framework that contains three modules all of which implement a MVVM pattern. Each module has it's own user interface in which the user can give some data and this data can then be communicated to the server. 
Now, my question is: do modules in a Prism application only refer to different parts of a user interface? Can I also create a module that would implement the communication with the server or should I create another project for this?
Let's say the communication with the server is implemented in a module, and I have a class called UserAccount and all other modules that have a user interface need to have access to it. Should the UserAccount be a part of the server communication module or a part of the Infrastracture?

In my opinion, I should implement the communication with the server in a module and the module should contain classes like UserAccount, but the Infrastructure should contain the created UserAccount object so that the it can be accessed from all the other modules.
Would this be a correct approach?

Also, could you recommend any prism documentation that deals with these kind of issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All types that are shared between modules should be in a separate shared assembly (Infrastructure serves this role for you?). This includes interface definitions and all custom types that will carry information.

Yes, your server communications module sounds like an excellent candidate for being its own module, especially if there are shared resources involved in the server communication.

Edit - Shared Assembly

- **Assembly1**: Imports one instance of `IMyServiceModule`
- **Assembly2**: Implements `IMyServiceModule` and exports an instance
- **Assembly3**: The shared assembly. Defines the `IMyServiceModule` interface and supporting classes. Referenced by Assembly1 and Assembly2

Why? To allow loose coupling of modules and avoid circular references.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "separate shared assembly"? Let's say I have a class and a ViewModel from one module A creates an instance of that class. A ViewModel from module B need to access the object created by ViewModule from module A. How should this happen? Should ViewModel from module B access it directly from ViewModel from module A or should this be done indirectly (and how?).